# How to display count of documents beside webpart title of a document library ?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

A requirement in our project is, we have to show the count of documents beside web part title name. I have tried using Data view web part (using XSLT) but unable to display the count beside the title.

Can you please suggest any other alternative to meet the above requirement without using custom code?

Comment: Try http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com for non-coding related questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total count of the documents in a document library  you can get from

**xsl:value-of select="count(/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row)"**

Or

Open the data view web part properties and on the General tab select the show view footer. It will show the count of the documents